# Refactor Help> For loop mapping CGPoints, and SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, for-loop, cgpoint

Hi I am new to programming and I have been learning SpriteKit. (although this is a general purpose programming question.) I have hard coded values, and reused the same image over and over. A coding no no from what I understand. Can someone help me learn this by refactoring with loops I assume.

I am creating a row of 20 dashed empty card spots and placing 4 at a time to a screen size centered at the bottom of the screen. I have added these empty spots (just one card image used over and over) as a "child" to the rack.

Side Note: Since this is a general programming question if you are not familiar with SpriteKit my CGPoints are mapped to the racks coordinate system and not to the screen coordinates... if that confused you..

I have attempted to create the refactored code at the bottom but I am stuck because the node.positions are tied to SKSpriteNodes and looping that seems to be puzzling me.

Here is what I have:

```
-(SKSpriteNode*)createBottomRack
{
    self.rack = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor]   size:CGSizeMake(10240.0, 200)];
    self.rack.position = CGPointMake(0.0,150.0);
    self.rack.zPosition = 0;
    self.rack.name = @"bottomRack";

    // Screen 1
    SKSpriteNode *number0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    // Screen 1 positions
    number0.position = CGPointMake(212, 0.0);
    number1.position = CGPointMake(412, 0.0);
    number2.position = CGPointMake(612, 0.0);
    number3.position = CGPointMake(812, 0.0);

    // Screen 2
    SKSpriteNode *number4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number7 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];

    // Screen 2 positions
    number4.position =CGPointMake(1236.0, 0.0);
    number5.position =CGPointMake(1436.0, 0.0);
    number6.position =CGPointMake(1636.0, 0.0);
    number7.position =CGPointMake(1836.0, 0.0);

    // Screen 3
     SKSpriteNode *number8 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
     SKSpriteNode *number9 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
     SKSpriteNode *number10 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
     SKSpriteNode *number11 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];

    // Screen 3 positions
    number8.position =CGPointMake(2260.0, 0.0);
    number9.position =CGPointMake(2460.0, 0.0);
    number10.position =CGPointMake(2660.0, 0.0);
    number11.position =CGPointMake(2860.0, 0.0);

    // Screen 4
    SKSpriteNode *number12 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number13 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number14 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number15 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];

    // Screen 4 positions
    number12.position =CGPointMake(3284.0, 0.0);
    number13.position =CGPointMake(3484.0, 0.0);
    number14.position =CGPointMake(3684.0, 0.0);
    number15.position =CGPointMake(3884.0, 0.0);

    // Screen 5
    SKSpriteNode *number16 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number17 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number18 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    SKSpriteNode *number19 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];

    // Screen 5 positions
    number16.position =CGPointMake(4308.0, 0.0);
    number17.position =CGPointMake(4508.0, 0.0);
    number18.position =CGPointMake(4708.0, 0.0);
    number19.position =CGPointMake(4908.0, 0.0);

    // Add dashedCards in position on screen
    [self.rack addChild:number0];
    [self.rack addChild:number1];
    [self.rack addChild:number2];
    [self.rack addChild:number3];
    [self.rack addChild:number4];
    [self.rack addChild:number5];
    [self.rack addChild:number6];
    [self.rack addChild:number7];
    [self.rack addChild:number8];
    [self.rack addChild:number9];
    [self.rack addChild:number10];
    [self.rack addChild:number11];
    [self.rack addChild:number12];
    [self.rack addChild:number13];
    [self.rack addChild:number14];
    [self.rack addChild:number15];
    [self.rack addChild:number16];
    [self.rack addChild:number17];
    [self.rack addChild:number18];
    [self.rack addChild:number19];

    return self.rack;
}
```

Here is where I currently am in refactoring...

```
NSMutableArray *dashesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *dash = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
    [dashesArray addObject:dash];

}
```

This is it because if I make a loop holding generically numbered SKSpriteNodes I don't see how I map those to the positions....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the *x* coordinate for the `position` of each node is pretty straightforward:

- *x* starts at 212
- Subsequent nodes are 200px to the right of the previous node
- Every 5th node is 424px (instead of 200px) to the right of the previous node

The code for that looks like this:

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)createBottomRack
{
    self.rack = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(10240.0, 200)];
    self.rack.position = CGPointMake(0.0,150.0);
    self.rack.zPosition = 0;
    self.rack.name = @"bottomRack";

    float x = 212.0, y = 0.0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *dash = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
        dash.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
        [self.rack addChild:dash];

        // Calculate the next x coordinate
        x += (i % 4 == 3) ? 424.0 : 200;
    }

    return self.rack;
}
```

Comment: This is very readable, and helpful. I am confused how to read the //Calculate the next x coordinate, is it "as long as x is greater then its initial position it will add/equal the i value up to 4 [then I am confused?] then x equals 424.0 or it will equal 200.0. The remainder of 4 == 3 is what has me confused.

Comment: @iOSLearner I've updated the line that's confusing you so it's a little more readable. Array indices in Objective-C are zero-based, so the first element as an index of 0. `i % 4 == 3` is `true` for every 4th value of `i` when we increment it by 1. You could write `(i+1) % 4 == 0` but that means that's an addition computation, i.e. `(i+1)` for each step. My way just eliminates that addition.

Comment: Thanks. I get what the line 'x += (i % 4 == 3) ? 424.0 : 200;' is doing...It is either going to be moved by 200 or 424 depending on if it is the last increment in 4 increments but I don't understand how the == 3 comes into play.. That is pretty inspiring and cool none the less. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @iOSLearner It's pure mathematics. Take the 4th, 8th, and 12th node. They have indices 3, 7, and 11. 3 % 4 == 3. 7 % 4 == 3, 11 % 4 == 3. Therefore, if i % 4 == 3, then i is the index of the last node in a block of 4.

Comment: Ha, totally get it now. Thanks big help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to programming, I suggest you spend some time learning how arrays work, and how they are used:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

and their iOS implementation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

For starters, you can declare two arrays, one containing the SKSpriteNodes, and the other containing the position points:

```
   //Declare these in @interface
        @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sprites;
        @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *points;

    //This will contain the SKSpriteNodes
        self.sprites =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //This will contain the points, we initialise it with the hard-coded values.
    //You have to wrap the values in an object type of NSValue of the array to accept it
        self.points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(212, 0.0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(412, 0.0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(612, 0.0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(812, 0.0)],
                       //Put the rest of the values here... for the moment it will do
                       nil];

    //Now for each declared point, we create a SKSpriteNode, insert it into the array and add it to "rack"

//for will loop over eacg point you have defined.
        for (NSValue *point in self.points){

//This will be a temporary object we create to add it into the array.
            SKSpriteNode *node =[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dashedCard"];
            node.position = [point CGPointValue];
            [self.sprites addObject:node];
            [self.rack addChild:node];
        }
```

As you get more experience you will find many other ways to improve the code, but take your time studying the code and basic data structures. Good luck!

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Still hard coding the values, but assigning the SKSpriteNode "dashedCard" to the points in a for loop is really helpful. I assume the "for in" is specifically for enumerating over arrays mostly?

Comment: Yes, it iterates over the values of the array allowing you to access each value of the array in turn as a local variable.

Comment: The `for (... in ...)` syntax is called **fast enumeration**.